# Replacing graphical sudo prompts with sudo command

Tags: sudo, authentication

I'm trying to replace `gksudo`, `pkexec` and its ilk with `sudo`. However, I'm told that using `sudo <graphical_program>` is a [bad idea](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus).

Would the following work as a decent replacement?

```
sudo -H <graphical_program>
```

Or do I have to do other things as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://bbs.archbang.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2429#p2429) post suggests that you're right (I never knew of that `--debug` option).  However, `sudo -H` is one extra key press on the keyboard compared to `gksudo` ;-)